# React Native, onPress not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Cannot get any output from my function `test()` which I have written in `Boxes.js` when I add `onPress={test}` to my `View` tag in `Dice.js`.
I have tried to add `test()` on tags like `Text`, then it works, but not when I put it on the View tag.

Boxes.js:

```
import react from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

import Dice from "./Dice";
import PatternDivider from "./PatternDivider";

export function test() {
  console.log("hi");
}

export default class Boxes extends react.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.box}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Advice #117</Text>
        <Text style={styles.advice}>
          It is easy to sit up and take notice, what's difficult is getting uu
          and taking action
        </Text>
        <PatternDivider />
        <Dice />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Dice.js:

```
import react from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

import { test } from "./Boxes";

export default class Dice extends react.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.circle} onPress={test}>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/icon-dice.png")}
          style={styles.dice}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna `Dice` to be clickable, use one the components that handles press events, like [`Pressable`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable). Not all components accept an `onPress` property, `View` is one of them.

```
import react from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Pressable } from "react-native";

import { test } from "./Boxes";

export default class Dice extends react.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Pressable style={styles.circle} onPress={test}>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/icon-dice.png")}
          style={styles.dice}
        />
      </Pressable>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native's View component doesn't have an `onPress` property https://reactnative.dev/docs/view